# Callback NodeJS Javascript function from multithreaded C++ addon

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, multithreading, v8

I have a multithreaded C++ addon that does some background processing and I need to have it periodically callback to a Javascript function that I wrote in my NodeJS server.

I understand that this involves using uv_async_send(), since it needs to get executed in the main thread, but thus far I haven't been able to figure out how to do it.

Is there a simple example out there that I've missed?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Finally, this was not too difficult once I understood what the the uv_* functions do:

**1) Expose a function in the addon to allow Node to set the Javascript cb that will be periodically called back to:**

```
Callback* cbPeriodic; // keep cbPeriodic somewhere
NAN_METHOD(setPeriodicCb) {
    cbPeriodic = new Callback(info[0].As<Function>());
    //...
}
```

**2) Init UV with an `uv_async_t` instance and a function that will be executed in the main thread by UV when our worker thread calls `uv_async_send()`**

```
uv_async_t async; // keep this instance around for as long as we might need to do the periodic callback
uv_loop_t* loop = uv_default_loop();
uv_async_init(loop, &async, asyncmsg);

void asyncmsg(uv_async_t* handle) {
  // Called by UV in main thread after our worker thread calls uv_async_send()
  //    I.e. it's safe to callback to the CB we defined in node!
  Nan::HandleScope scope;
  v8::Isolate* isolate = v8::Isolate::GetCurrent();
  Local<Value> argv[] = { v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Hello world") };
  cbPeriodic->Call(1, argv);
}
```

**3) Call `uv_async_send` from a worker thread, passing our async instance above, whenever we need to do the periodic callback**

```
uv_async_send(&async);
```

**4) Finally, when we no longer need to execute the callback ever again, clean things up:**

```
uv_close((uv_handle_t*) &async, NULL);
```

---

***Addendum:***

Since I wrote this answer I've run into other issues and finally learned some lessons about libuv. For completeness, you should understand:

- Aside from `uv_async_send`, **all** libuv functions may ***only*** be called from the the main loop thread! (I had seen it mentioned that the others were not thread-safe, but this is too weak of a statement.) Even, for example, `uv_async_init` and `uv_close` must be called from the main loop thread.
- If your `uv_async_t` instance is dynamically allocated, note that you may not free up memory until uv_close makes its callback to let you know that it is safe to do so.

I.e.:

```
auto async = new uv_async_t();
...
uv_close((uv_handle_t*)async, [](uv_handle_t* handle) {
    delete handle;
});
```