# Calling JS function multiple times from node addon

Tags: javascript, c++, node-addon-api

Edit: apparently it's not clear, guess I'll make it more concise.

Node application is built, uses a native addon. I need to pass in a Javascript function from this project through node-addon-api into my C++ addon. Then, I need to be able to call that function from C++ multiple times. The issue arose when I found out I am unable to save the reference to the Javascript function due to the napi_env (required for calling the function) being protected from caching.

Could not find any clear answers or examples on the internet regarding how to do this, looking for tips.

Original:

as the title describes, I need to figure out a way to call a JS function multiple times in my addon. Generic use case is that my addon does some long running commands and needs to periodically push a status update back to the javascript.

I thought the best approach would be to have the user pass in a function (which just appends to a text block) for my addon to call (so it can write the updates), this way the javascript side can decide where it gets displayed.

I have experimented to get this working. Found out that my original way of saving the function in a persistent napi_value doesn't work since you cannot save napi_env as well.

I found this thread, which I think is the closest to what I need, but I can't manage to translate the Nan to napi_ so it would work with what I'm using. [Callback NodeJS Javascript function from multithreaded C++ addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36987273/callback-nodejs-javascript-function-from-multithreaded-c-addon)

Also attempted passing in an EventEmitter, but similar problem as above.

Can anyone give some pointers on if I am heading in the right direction? Perhaps help me dig up a few examples on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not clear.  Assuming you are using Javascript in Node, have a look at [FFI](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffi) which allows one to loading and calling dynamic libraries using Javascript.

Alternatively one can just execute a function as follows from the command line:

```
/usr/bin/node yourjsfunctionfilehere.js
```

You can also [pass command line parameters](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/command-line/how-to-parse-command-line-arguments/) to the called JS function.

Comment: Have you looked at [child processes](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_stdin) it can be used to send messages between different processes?